# I have been using vimeo package in nextjs to upload a video but its throwing an invalid parameter

Tags: video, next.js, vimeo

I have trying to upload video and also granted all permission in vimeo, but its throwing error 2002. here's my (Nextjs) code.

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "./";
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.log(err, fields, files);
      
        let file_name = files
        client.upload(
            file_name,
            {                   
                'name': 'videoName',
                'description': "videoDescription",                 
                'locale': "en",
                'content_rating': ["safe"],
                'size': 31032306,              
                "upload": {
                    "approach": "tus",
                    "size": 31032306
                  }
            },

            function (uri) {
                console.log('Your video URI is: ' + uri);
            },
            function (bytes_uploaded, bytes_total) {
                var percentage = (bytes_uploaded / bytes_total * 100).toFixed(2)
                console.log(bytes_uploaded, bytes_total, percentage + '%')
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('Failed because: ' + error)
            }
        )

    });
};
```

and here is the error:

> Failed because: Unable to initiate an upload. [Error: {"invalid_parameters":[{"field":"upload.size","error_code":2002,"error":"Something strange occurred. Please try again. "," developer message ":" The required body is missing from request."}], "error": "You have provided an invalid parameter. Please contact developer of this application.","link":null,"developer_message":"The parameters passed to this API endpoint didn't pass Vimeo's validation. Please check the invalid_parameters list for more information.","error_code":2204}]

Comment: It's complaining about the `upload.size` field in the request. Have you tried removing it?